# Should Forked Repositories only Push Changes?

Tags: git

In an attempt to fork a GitHub repository onto my BitBucket account, I've taken the following steps:

```
[Created the BitBucket repository]
[Cloned it locally]
git remote add upstream [GitHub url]
git pull upstream master
git branch --track github upstream/master
git checkout master
[ Made some changes ]
git push -u origin
```

This appears to be pushing the whole ~250MB collection of files to BitBucket. My hope is that there's some way to only push the changes and have everything on BitBucket be relevant to the remote on which it was based.

Is it possible to have a forked repository that only contains the changes from the point-of-forking or must forks contain all the files in a project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *This appears to be pushing the whole ~250MB collection of files to BitBucket. My hope is that there's some way to only push the changes and have everything on BitBucket be relevant to the remote on which it was based.*

There isn't.

Each Git repository is a complete copy of the full history of the repository. This is one of the reasons why you don't put huge files into Git, they will always be there even if you delete them.

Remotes are local. Sounds very zen. Which is to say everything you're doing with `git remote` only applies to your repository. When you `git push` the remote doesn't know anything about your local repository.

So `git pull upstream master` must obtain the complete history of `master`, including any merged branches, from Github (minus whatever pieces you already might have had locally). Similarly, `git push origin` must push the complete history of `master` up to Bitbucket. Fortunately you only have to do this once.

Github and Bitbucket do tricks to share space within their own repositories, like they don't copy the whole repo when you fork, but they won't share with each other.

---

Your best option, for a lot of reasons, is to slim down your repository. 250 MB is pretty big. That's the size of large projects like Ruby with 20 years of history.

If you have large files in your repository bloating out your repository size, you can fix this using [Git Large File Storage](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/git-large-file-storage-in-bitbucket-829078514.html). This will store the content of the file in cloud storage and only the history is stored in your repository. You can [convert existing history to LFS with the BFG Repo Cleaner](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-bfg-to-migrate-a-repo-to-git-lfs-834233484.html).

Comment: Turns out it's more like 450MB. At a glance, because they've got the sources of many of their open-source dependencies included as well.

Comment: @HammerBro. Very old school. A proper dependency system can replace that. If it's someone else's project, perhaps you can ask them to maintain a Bitbucket mirror. Good luck.